# Horizontal rebar protruding from foundation

Tags: concrete, foundation, rebar

On a new build, in Grants Pass, Oregon, should rebar protrude horizontally from a stem wall foundation? The concrete is poured. It is no Ufer, it is rebar - looks to be used to assist in supporting stem wall forms. Maybe should have been pulled, when concrete was wet, but now it all sticks out. So now anyone doing work under the house could be injured. Or rust & cracking can occur?? Also - should a footing be poured on top of grade?

Comment: You're going to have to provide a _whole_ lot more info. What do your plans call for?

Comment: In some cases yes, it depends if additional future structure or engineering stamp required it, more info is needed, I had to terminate to a steel plate but that was in Benton county on a below grade wall.

Comment: You might as well have asked whether rebar should point north. Well, _maybe_.

Comment: Is this a residence? Has the concrete been poured yet? Does the rebar extend through the formwork? How far does it extend? Can you post a picture?

Comment: Has the Building Inspector signed off on the concrete pour? Has the foundation been installed and approved? Do the rebar point out from the wall or up from the wall?

Comment: Pictures would be good - [edit] some in, if possible. I wonder if you are looking at form ties that have not yet been broken off and thinking they are rebar.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an Ufer ground?  Ufer grounds are your very best friend, because they are the finest grounding electrode money can buy.  The biggest problem is people forgetting to have their concrete contractor install one - then the electrician must install ground rods, which then become a hazard to landscaping.

Comment: The concrete is poured. It is no Ufer, it is rebar - looks to be used to assist in supporting stem wall forms. Maybe should have been pulled, when concrete was wet, but now it all sticks out. So now anyone doing work under the house could be injured. Or rust & cracking can occur?? Also - should a footing be poured on top of grade?

Comment: ***Please*** include a picture. "Supporting stemwall forms" sounds very much like form ties. Those are not removed when the concrete is wet, they are designed to be broken off after it's set. The ends break off, the center remains in place. They are distinct from rebar in both form and function.

Answer (score 1):

The only acceptable reason the rebars protrude from a stem wall foundation, or a beam/slab, is for the consideration of future expansion of the building. The rebars shall be protected by coating or galvanization. Without the protection, the rebars eventually will rust out and lose their nominal strength.